# Make a header of a view page to appear only in the view's first page

Tags: views, 10

I have a view-page with a pager of about **10 pager-pages**.

This view also has a a view-header. The text of this header repeats itself in all pager-pages of that view, which is a bit funny because in page 2 or even in page 10 the user could read the same header text "welcome to my blog".

How to make a header of a view page to appear only in the view's first page?

Comment: I rolled back the edit because this is solely about a header of a view. Other headers are just not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hook_preprocess_views_view__HOOK() hook (in .module/theme file) for display header conditionally:

```
function Mymodulename_preprocess_views_view__machine_name_of_view(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $pager_number = $view->pager->current_page;
  // current page key value start from 0 
  // Added condition header should display only for first page
  if($pager_number != 0){
     unset($vars['header']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the Filter Twig module:

```
composer require 'drupal/filter_twig:^2.2'
drush en filter_twig
```

Visit */admin/config/content/formats/add*, enter the name "Views Twig", check "Replaces Twig value" and save.

In the View add a Header: Global: Text area, select the text format *Views Twig* and fill in the text:

```
{% if [view:current-page] == 1 %}
  Page 1
{% endif %}
```